# JSON filtration via map returns results for matches and undefined for non-matches

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that filters JSON data. It looks like this:

```
    var orderInfo = Products.map( function(order) {
 if( filter.node.material.value === "Leather"){
     var info = { "Title": order.node.title
                 }
     return info;
 }
});
console.log(orderInfo);]
```

This actually works as intended, but for all of the results which do not meet the criteria, they are returned as "undefined". I only want to return the objects which match the filtration though.

Is there a way that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `reduce` instead of `map`:

```
var orderInfo = Products.reduce((acc, order) => {
  if (order.node.material.value === "Leather") {
    acc.push({ "Title": order.node.title });
  }
   
  return acc;
}, [])
```

If you don't want to transform the data, and just wanted to return the matching orders, you would use `filter`:

```
var orderInfo = Products.filter(order => order.node.material.value === 'Leather')
```